# Hide menu item on log in with Umbraco / XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt, umbraco

I have a small issue with hiding a certain menu item upon login in Umbraco / XSLT.

I have this piece of XSLT that outputs menu items

```
<li>
    <a href="{$url}" class="{$class}">      
        <xsl:if test="$currentPage/ancestor-or-self::*/@id = ./@id">
            <xsl:attribute name="class">active</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:if test="$node/@level = 3">
                <i class="{$iconClass}"></i>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:if>   
        <xsl:value-of select="$node/@nodeName" />           
    </a>
    <xsl:if test="$active">
        <xsl:call-template name="list">
            <xsl:with-param name="parent" select="$node" />
        </xsl:call-template>    
    </xsl:if>
</li>
```

What I want is to be able to exlude menu items that have true in the property "hideAtLogin", upon login.

I have tried with

```
<xsl:if test="umbraco.library:IsLoggedOn = 'false' and hideAtLogin = ''">
...
</xsl:if>
```

But that doesn't work...

when `hideAtLogin` isn't selected (= false), the item should be shown regardless of login or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work with

```
<xsl:if test="not(umbraco.library:IsLoggedOn()) or (umbraco.library:IsLoggedOn() and hideAtLogin != 1)">
...
</xsl:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just 2 suggestions:
Have you already tried to change

```
 <xsl:if test="umbraco.library:IsLoggedOn = 'false' ..">..</xsl:if>
```

into

```
 <xsl:if test="umbraco.library:IsLoggedOn() = false() ..">..</xsl:if>
```

and in case this still won't work, could it be a server issue as mentioned here for someone with a similar problem?

[Umbraco.Library.IsLoggedOn() does not work from XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361706/umbraco-library-isloggedon-does-not-work-from-xslt)

Issue there was that the session was not available by XSLT because of server configuration and the web.config had to be adjusted.